# The probability that $X=Y$ if $(X,Y)$ admits a density

Tags: probability

I am trying to answer the following question:

> Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)$. What is the probability that $X=Y$?

My idea was to use the definition

$$P((X,Y)\in A)=\iint_Af(x,y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y$$

where $A=\{\text{all the points on }x=y\}$. However, I am unsure how to solve this integral. I would love to hear if you have a better idea.

Comment: If the joint density exists, then the integral you wrote is zero.

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is a continuous random vector this probability is zero.

Comment: $\int_{\{(x,y):x=y\}}f(x,y)\,dxdy=0$ since the Lebesgue measure of $\{(x,y):x=y\}$ is $0$.

Comment: Thats what I thought but I got stuck trying to show it... what im writing in the bounds? x to x on the inner one and -inf to inf on the outer?  edit: Just saw oliver's comment, not sure what is Lebesgue measure

Comment: To various commenters: Is the probability necessarily $0$ as there may be dependence between $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: The comments saying zero are incorrect in general; take $Y\equiv X$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio In the case $Y=X$, I would say that there does not exist a joint density function for $Y=X$, since no $f$ would satisfy the integral definition given in OP's post for all measurable sets $A$.

Comment: @angryavian Ah noted, thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Golden_ratio: the law of $(X,X)$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure on the plane. In fact is singular w.r.r Lebesgue measure on the plane

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks; so the assumption of a joint density in the problem is essential

Comment: @Golden_Ratio: correct, unless of course the dominant measure ( Lebesgue in this case) were different. For example counting measure on the $Z^2$ lattice and both $X$ and $Y$ take integer values for example